# potencia de dos, proceso inverso, obtener la serie de factores dada la suma de potencias

Tags: vb.net

Hace tiempo vi un código que manejaba múltiples opciones, numerando cada opción y obteniendo
un valor representativo elevando el numero 2 a la potencia N menos 1.

Ejemplo:

[N] -- [Potencia]

1 -- 2^0= 1

2 -- 2^1= 2

3 -- 2^2= 4

4 -- 2^3= 8

Investigando encontré el enlace: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two

Si se eligen diferentes [N] y se suman los valores de sus potencias obtenemos un entero único para dicha combinación.

Un algoritmo en programación es sencillo de obtener (Rutina 1).

Pero el proceso inverso, es un poco mas elaborado, es decir dado un valor X, obtener la secuencia de N de potencia 2 que lo conforman.
Investigue a cerca el tema, y quizá ignoro el nombre del algoritmo, pero no encontré alguna referencia, así que lo programe.
El punto que no termina de convencerme es que en esta solución (Rutina 3), se recorre de la [N] mas baja hasta la [N] inmediato anterior al valor buscado
Y se resta la diferencia, y de forma recursiva, la diferencia se procesa de la misma manera.

¿Existe un algoritmo mas eficiente para dado un Valor X, obtener la serie binaria(base-2) que lo conforma?

**Rutina 1**
Suma potencias, dada una serie de enteros

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Según una serie de enteros, obtiene un único valor (binario o serie binaria
    ''' Uso:
    ''' Dim ArrInt As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)({5, 3, 1})
    ''' Console.WriteLine(ValorN2(ArrInt).ToString())
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="ArrInt"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Friend Function ValorN2(LVal As List(Of Integer)) As Integer
        Dim Valor As Integer
        If LVal.Count > 0 Then
            For Each I As Integer In LVal
                ''    Acumula el valor elevado a N-1, de cada entero 
                Valor = Valor + Math.Pow(2, I - 1)
            Next
        Else
            Valor = 0
        End If
        Return Valor
    End Function
```

**Rutina 2**
Obtiene la serie de valores que genero el entero dado

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Lista las opciones según un valor dado
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Valor">Valor</param>
    ''' <param name="Orden">1: Orden de opciones ascendente, Otro, orden descendente</param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Friend Function ListaN2(Valor As Integer, Optional Orden As Integer = 0) As List(Of Integer)
        Dim LVal As New List(Of Integer)
        ValoresListaN2(Valor, LVal)
        If Orden = 1 Then LVal.Reverse()
        Return LVal
    End Function
```

**Rutina 3**
Función recursiva que obtiene el valor máximo anterior elevando 2 a la potencia-1
**´¿se puede optimizar esta función?**

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Segun un valor, devuelve la serie numerica que lo describe
    ''' Maximo 30 numeros (De acuerdo a mis necesidades, puede incrementarse)
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Valor">Entero a evaluar</param>
    ''' <param name="LVal">Lista de eneteros que se obtienen</param>
    Private Sub ValoresListaN2(Valor As Integer, ByRef LVal As List(Of Integer))
        If Valor > 0 Then
            For I = 1 To 30
                Dim Val As Integer = Math.Pow(2, I - 1)
                If Val = Valor Then
                    LVal.Add(I)
                    Exit For
                End If
                If Val > Valor Then
                    LVal.Add(I - 1)
                    ''    Recursividad
                    ValoresListaN2(Valor - Math.Pow(2, I - 2), LVal)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

**Rutina 3 Mejorada**
Con base a la información de @Juan_m_2

```
    Private Function ValoresListaN2(Valor As Integer, Optional Orden As Integer = 0) As List(Of Integer)
        Dim Val As Integer = Valor
        Dim LVal As New List(Of Integer)

        If Valor = 1 Then
            LVal.Add(1)
        ElseIf Valor > 0 Then
            Dim Log As Double
            Dim Entero As Integer
            Dim Decimo As Double = 1

            Do While Decimo > 0
                Log = Math.Log(Valor) / Math.Log(2)
                Entero = Conversion.Int(Log)
                Decimo = Log - Entero
                LVal.Add(Entero + 1)
                Valor = Valor - (Math.Pow(2, Entero))
            Loop
        End If

        If Orden = 1 Then LVal.Reverse()
        Return LVal
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Te presento otra opción, la cual no sé si será más eficiente, pero ciertamente es más corta y creo que más fácil de entender

Digamos que tenemos el número `22` cuyos `N` son:

- 5
- 3
- 2

`22` en binario es `10110` y digamos que ese número binario está como `String`.

Un `String` tiene indices (como un array) de izquierda a derecha:

| Indice | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Número | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Ahora bien, los indices que tú tienes son de derecha a izquierda (inversos) y además comienzan en `1`, es decir:

| Indice | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Número | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Lo primero que debes notar es que es necesario convertir los indices de la primera forma a la segunda, para esto basta con restar el largo del string

```
indice_inverso = Largo_string - indice
```

Es decir:

- `5 - 0 = 5`
- `5 - 1 = 4`
- `5 - 2 = 3`
- `5 - 3 = 2`
- `5 - 4 = 1`

Luego notaras que en el binario `10110` solo nos interesa los indices en los cuales exista un `1`

| Indice | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Número | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| ¿Nos interesa? | si | no | si | si | no |

Y nos da `5,3,2`

Entonces:

- Para convertir un `Integer` a una representación binaria en `String`, simplemente hacemos: `Convert.ToString(Numer_a_convertir, 2)`
- Luego recorremos el string y guaramos los indices inversos en el caso que el valor almacenado sea `1`

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim LVal = ValoresListaN2(22)
    For Each i As Integer In LVal
        Console.WriteLine(i)
    Next
    'Imprime:
    '5
    '3
    '2
End Sub

Private Function ValoresListaN2(Valor As Integer) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim x = Convert.ToString(Valor, 2)
    Dim LVal = New List(Of Integer)
    For i = 0 To x.Length - 1
        If x(i) = "1" Then
            LVal.Add(x.Length - i)
        End If
    Next
    Return LVal
End Function
```

Comment: Realice pruebas y funciona igual que el código que tengo, sin recursividad. Pero tu código es mucho mas limpio, y por lo que puedo ver también es mas eficiente.

Answer (score 0):

La función matematica que buscas es la del **logaritmo**, concretamente el logaritmo en base 2.

En VB tienes la función de logaritmo neperiano `Math.Log` la cual puedes usar para calcularlo.

Ej: 2^x=16 -> `Math.Log(16) / Math.Log(2)` -> x=4

Ej: 2^x=33 -> `Math.Log(33) / Math.Log(2)` -> x=5.04439411935845

- En caso de que quieras obtener el valor como número entero usa: `CInt(Math.Log(33) / Math.Log(2))` -> x=5

Comment: Con base a tu información, realice un ajuste en el código, y ahora ya no se se requiere recursividad.